# how to mock a class inside a controller?

Tags: grails

I have a controller method which inside it creates a domain instance and saves it. I need to simulate that this save fails so i am thinking of mocking this domain and for save method i throw an exception. Is there a way to mock the donor class.

```
def method(){

    ...

    Donor donor = new Donor()                           

    donor.properties = convertedParams

    donor.save(failOnError: true)

    ...

 }
```

I know how to mock a service that is used inside a controller

```
      def mock = new groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor(ExampleService)
        def exampleService = controller.exampleService
        mock.demand.exampleMethod(){ Long id, TransactionResponse tr ->
            throw new RegistrationActivationException(new IllegalStateException('something went wrong'), [])
        }
        mock.use{
            controller.exampleService = new ExampleService()
            model = controller.exampleMethod()
        }
```

So, the code above will mock out the ExampleService service used in the controller. Is there a way to do mocks like that but not for a service but for a domain that is instantiated inside a method like in the first code block above. I need to mock out the Donor class and when save is called then i need to throw an exception in order to simulate and test what happens when the donor save fails.

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: what test framework do you use?

Comment: Its looks as a unit testing domain scenario. So you may find useful read unit testing domain section in grails documentation http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#unitTestingDomains

Comment: ok this was the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220338/making-domain-savefailonerrortrue-fail-when-doing-integration-tests/38222784#38222784

Answer (score 1):

> I need to mock out the Donor class and when save is called then i need to throw an exception in order to simulate and test what happens when the donor save fails.

This seems like a very convoluted way to achieve an exception being thrown on save. Instead, it seems you could just try to save an instance of `Donor` that doesn't match it's constraints. Assuming `Donor` has at least one property that is not null, this should achieve the same thing

```
new Donor().save(failOnError: true)
```